# Things to Consider While Installing a Radiator

Tags: cooling-system, design

I have been using a KTM Duke 390 engine in my formula car. The engine is overheating, so I thought of using a twin parallel type radiator setup.

What are the points to be considered before I set the radiators in this fashion?

Comment: i suppose you'll get a lot more help searching KTM motorcycle forums.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rather obscure topic to focus on, but still relevant; Clamps. Considering which type of clamps you're going to use is necessary based on what material(s) are present in the cooling system. If you have Plastic Water-necks, or anything plastic involved, you're going to need a Constant-Tension style Clamp. Using a Worm-Style Clamp will result in the clamp either being too loose and/or causing damage during expansion and contraction cycles. The Constant-Tension, or "Spring" Clamps, can expand and contract so they move with the contraction cycles, rather than fight against them. Less stress on the hoses, less stress on the water-necks.

Answer (score 0):

Before you spring for another radiator and plumbing, look at other aspects of your cooling system.  Check out this white paper: http://www.tbucketeer.com/threads/cooling-secrets.17629/

This guy has been there and done that.  And I hear he is brilliant and charismatic, too.

Comment: Be good to provide some salient points rather than just an offsite link.